# How using urls in cells to loop to collect text from web pages and set value in another column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function Looping() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Clock'),
      range,
      values_array; 
  
  range = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
  values_array = range.getValues();
  var loop = JSON.stringify(values_array);
  
  for (var key in loop) {
    
    var column = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B2:B');
    var values = column.getValues();
    var ct = 0;
    while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
      ct++;
    }
    
    var webpage = UrlFetchApp.fetch(key).getContentText();
    sheet.getRange(ct+2, 2).setValue(webpage);
  }
}
```

`Column A` values are **urls**

I want to use these values to put in `Column B` the text that exists on these web pages.

For that I'm trying to create a looping that finds the first empty cell, collects the existing value in the web page and set that value in the cell.

But the error appears saying `Exception: Invalid request: http://0`.

Because `key` is delivering numbers instead of url's, what should I do to solve this problem?

Aditional info -> my `Column A` values are:

```
URLS
https://int.soccerway.com/national/colombia/copa-colombia/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/brazil/paranaense-1/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/chile/copa-chile/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/colombia/primera-b/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var loop = JSON.stringify(values_array);
```

only gives you a string representation of values_array, which is array of arrays. Use

```
  var loop = range.getValues().flat();
```

instead:

```
function Looping() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Clock'),
      range,
      values_array; 
  
  range = sheet.getRange('A2:A');

  var loop = range.getValues().flat();
  
  for (var key of loop) {
    var column = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('B2:B');
    var values = column.getValues();
    var ct = 0;
    while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
      ct++;
    }
    
    var webpage = UrlFetchApp.fetch(key).getContentText();
    sheet.getRange(ct+2, 2).setValue(webpage);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello my friend @GoranK , unfortunately when doing the tests the error ```Exception: Invalid request: http://0``` persists

Comment: I updated the script, use for (var key of loop)  instead of for (var key in loop)

Comment: Hi @GoranK I wasn't aware of the ```of``` when using inside ```for```, thank you very much and I'm sorry for withdrawing the approval of the question, but as the error persisted I thought it was better to do so but I've already returned it with due thanks, thank you very much for your time and attention!